# Animation lags on device, but not in Simulator

Tags: swift, core-animation

I want to trigger a **CAAnimation** with a Button. In playground and in the simulator, this works exactly as I want it to. However, when I run the same code on a device, the animation happens only after a short delay.

Apparently, the issue only happens on iOS 11.2.6. I updated my device and can now not reproduce the issue anymore. Can anyone confirm, or find out, how it would work on iOS 11.2.6?

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    let animatedView = UIView()

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        // Add a button
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 200, height: 50)
        button.setTitle("Animate", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tap), for: .touchUpInside)

        // Set color and frame of the view, that is animated.
        animatedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        animatedView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50)

        // Add the views to the view hierarchy
        view.addSubview(animatedView)
        view.addSubview(button)
        self.view = view
    }

    /// On Tap create an animation, that changes the position of the animated view.
    @objc func tap() {
        let originalY = animatedView.layer.position.y
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.y")
        animation.fromValue = originalY
        animation.toValue = 300.0
        animation.duration = 1.0
        animatedView.layer.add(animation, forKey: "positionAnimation")
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into using `UIView.animate(...)` ;)

Comment: Also, you generally don't want to override `loadView` because then you can't use your view controller from a storyboard/XIB. Better to override `viewDidLoad` and do your setup there.

Comment: @GuyKogus I specifically need ```CAAnimation```, as I want to animate the layer. Also ```loadView``` is overwritten here only for example purposes, so that it also works in playground and people can easily test it.
Also by now Apple recommends using ```UIViewPropertyAnimator``` to animate views.

Comment: As you've written it, this animates the view's layout outside its view's bounds, which is very rarely a good idea. Is this really what you mean to do? Generally you should not manipulate the view's root layer directly. Either manipulate the view, or create a sublayer and manipulate that.

Comment: @gebirgsbärbel Can you give a gif for this problem?

Comment: @RobNapier Good hint. I tried to make sure to only change the layer inside of the view bounds. But then I still have the same issue.

Comment: @trungduc I cannot make a gif, because I updated my phone and now it does not happen anymore :/

Comment: So you are asking us to test for you?????

Comment: @matt No, I am not. I just added my finding, that the bug only happens on 11.2.6. I thought this information is helpful, as others had problems reproducing the issue.

Comment: Sorry, but if you're not asking us to test for you, on what grounds is the bounty offered?

Comment: I am sorry that it is not clear to you. I am trying to figure out, whether I am using the CAAnimation wrong in any ways that would fix the wrong behavior even on 11.2.6. Maybe I can formulate it in a better way?

Comment: I tested your code in an iPhone 7 with iOS 11.2.6 and in an iPhone 6 with iOS 11.2.2 and no apparent delay was present. I tested putting your initialisation code in loadView, viewDidLoad and in viewDidAppear (one comment suggested something like this). The three cases were all identical. Maybe something was wrong with your device before the update?

Comment: @MiguelIsla Thank you very much for your feedback. I did not see animation delays in any other apps with similar animations, but who knows.

Comment: This may be obvious but, did you try to reboot your device? Sometimes magic happens after rebooting :D

Comment: @MiguelIsla I tried to reboot, but the problem persisted. Weird. I hope now, that it really was a problem specific to my device and build. At least it does not happen anymore :/

Comment: @gebirgsbärbel glad to heart that it does not happen anymore. Good luck! ;)

Comment: > I have tested your code in 6s+ with 11.2.6 but not getting delay...
also working fine with other versions. **Maybe something going wrong with a specific device as based on device specification.**

Comment: What do you mean an error based device specification? After the iOS update it worked on the same device.

Comment: @gebirgsbärbel: On which device, you are getting this delay issue?

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary on a 6SE

Answer (score 0):

> Can you try this code with iOS 11.2.9, I have tested your code and it's working fine.

```
// MARK: Animations
public extension CALayer {

    var ani: CAAnimation {
        let startPointAnim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CAGradientLayer.startPoint))
        startPointAnim.fromValue = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.0)
        startPointAnim.toValue = CGPoint(x:0, y: 300)

        let endPointAnim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CAGradientLayer.endPoint))
        endPointAnim.fromValue = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        endPointAnim.toValue = CGPoint(x:2, y: 300)

        let animGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
        animGroup.animations = [startPointAnim, endPointAnim]
        animGroup.duration = 1.0
        animGroup.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)            
        return animGroup
    }

    func playAnimation(_ anim: SkeletonLayerAnimation, key: String) {
        recursiveSearch(inArray: skeletonSublayers,
                        leafBlock: { add(anim(self), forKey: key) }) {
                            $0.playAnimation(anim, key: key)
        }
    }

    func stopAnimation(forKey key: String) {
        recursiveSearch(inArray: skeletonSublayers,
                        leafBlock: { removeAnimation(forKey: key) }) {
                            $0.stopAnimation(forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```